# How to use NLTK BigramAssocMeasures.ch_sq

Tags: python, nlp, classification, nltk

I have list of words, I want to calculate the relatedness of two words by considering their co-occurrences. From a paper I found that it can be calculated using *Pearsson chi-square test*. Also I found `nltk.BigramAssocMeasures.ch_sq()` for calculating chi-sqare value.

Can I use this for my needs? How can I find chi-square value using nltk?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [this blog from Streamhacker](http://streamhacker.com/tag/chi-square/), it gives a good explanation with code examples.

> One of the best metrics for information gain is chi square. NLTK includes this in the BigramAssocMeasures class in the metrics package. To use it, first we need to calculate a few frequencies for each word: its overall frequency and its frequency within each class. This is done with a FreqDist for overall frequency of words, and a ConditionalFreqDist where the conditions are the class labels. Once we have those numbers, we can score words with the BigramAssocMeasures.chi_sq function, then sort the words by score and take the top 10000. We then put these words into a set, and use a set membership test in our feature selection function to select only those words that appear in the set. Now each file is classified based on the presence of these high information words.